# it's mine, but I don't say it. What is it?

Tags: riddle

> It's something that is mine, but yet others use it.
>
> It's more heard by me, than told by me.

**What is it?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be

> Your name

To answer on improvement, I think this is maybe a too easy and known riddle

Comment: That's right! Seems too easy tho.

Answer (score 3):

i guess it's

> your name
>  Others use it to call you, and you only say it to present yourself

Comment: that's right! But I think that Saeïdryl beated you by 2 seconds.

Comment: @ThimoDemey It's part of the game and often happen when the solution is a little bit to easy